# What is decoupling theory means on Tao Blog ? And what is its purpose in mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, inequalities

I accrossed on [Tao Blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2020/04/13/247b-notes-2-decoupling-theory/#comment-554928) a new theory for me which it is called "Decoupling theory", But I didn't find in the web  its definition and its purpose , I find only this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling_and_re-coupling) in wiki but this very far than what Tao discussed about that theory then What is decoupling theory  means on Tao Blog ? And what is its purpose in mathematics? Also no Tag here in MO about Decoupling theory to add .

Comment: It seems like the textbook mentioned in that post is a good place to start learning this theory: https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/fourier-restriction-decoupling-and-applications/277AEB2D8A1D3733C61A89FF623D50D1

Comment: But this is not free , I need for example  preliminary basics of that theory in wikipedia  if it is possible

Comment: This expository article from the Bourbaki Seminar seems useful for your purposes as well: https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.00119v1